# what is the good way to verify the user who rgistered on google signup?

Tags: flutter, authentication, google-signin, user-data

So on my mobile app, I wish to use Google login API for users registration. I'm saving the user details like `first name`,`Lastname`, `email`. The above data will be stored in Firestore.

My question is

> 1. will this `uid` and `OAuth Token` be useful later? if yes in what way it'll be useful?
> 2. After registration what should I do to verify the user and make the user login? Since we don't use any passwords for verification.

and what is the professional way of storing user data in a database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Oauth Token allows you to make calls to google API based on the authorised scopes. When working with identity attach make a call to...

```
https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/profile
```

Attach the Oauth token to the Authorization Header. If you get a response then it means the user is signed up.

With the Google Login API this is pretty much all you can do with the token. :)

Comment: what about login after user register how to verify the user using backend server?

Comment: You can use the same API as above and on the backend server using a rest call. Is there a specific Google API that you want to consume? The above Google API gives you the the authenticated users public profile.